# Should a GDAL vector dataset have a geotransform?

Tags: gdal, shapefile, ogr, c++

For example:  Does a shapefile have a geotransform?

The answer is probably:  No, a vector dataset does not have a geotransform, because the purpose of a geotransform is to transform between projection coordinates and *raster* coordinates.   But, I have not found anywhere that explicitly says that.

The documentation for `GDALDataset::GetGeoTransform()` ( https://gdal.org/api/gdaldataset_cpp.html ) says:

> The default transform ... should be returned even when a CE_Failure error is returned, such as for formats that don’t support transformation to projection coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL has raster API and vector API. GDALDataset belongs to the raster side but you should look at the vector API at https://gdal.org/api/index.html#vector-api.

API document does not explicitly say anything about what does not exist but because vector API does not define GeoTransform you can trust that shapefiles do not have it.